# Is it possible to use await outside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

This is my simple function in nodejs

```
const myFunction = async() => {
    const exercises = await Exercise.find({ workoutId })
    return exercises
}

const value = await myFunction()
```

But when I do `await` outside async function it throws an error

```
 await is a reserved word
```

Now how do I wait for the value outside the async function? Do I need to use callback or `.then`? Then what is the use `async and await`?

Comment: async/await is just syntactic sugar for Promises

Comment: async/await is not meant to make asynchronous code synchronous; it is meant to make it easier to write (and read) asynchronous code.

Comment: Yes, `await` replaces where you otherwise would have used `then`.

Comment: why do you want to use await outside async?

Comment: Duplicate Question, check the answer in the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77946819/2980414

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `await` outside an async function. 
one trick to 'bypass' this limit is to use async  IFEE:

```
const myFunction = async() => {
    const exercises = await Exercise.find({ workoutId })
    return exercises
};

(async () => {
    const value = await myFunction()
})()
```

Comment: is `const value` not limited to that self execution function's scope?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to the main question: *"Is it possible to use `await` outside `async` function"* **no**.

But there's multiple ways to access the value of an `async` operation, for example

```
const myFunction = async() => {
    const exercises = await Exercise.find({ workoutId })
    return exercises
}

const execution = () => {
    myFunction().then( ( exercises ) => {
        console.log( exercises );
    });
}
```

As `async` is a wrapper for `Promises` to access the result you need to use `then` and when the execution is completed that callback is fired.